# How to detach program from terminal and to attach it back?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, embedded-linux, multiplexing

I am working on an embedded project, where I need a program without external dependencies that works like screen or tmux. These two programs are not good because they need other libraries.

Since I only need to detach a program, being able to log-out and getting it back when I log-in again, I was wondering whether I can write a small program for that.

Do you know which calls (in C) I need to do to detach the program and to have it back?

Comment: run your program using nohup in terminal

Comment: nohup does not give me the possibility of interacting with the shell used for the program, as the others do. And by the way, it is painful to compile. Were I using openembedded to make the system, it would be easy, but this time I can just compile easy binaries because I don't have a complete cross compiling environment.

Comment: Did you look at the source code of either?

Comment: @WaleedKhan yes, but they are huge and I did not understand.

Comment: What other libraries does screen need? Normally all it uses is curses, but a minimal termcap library can do (even one that doesn't read any files, and just gives hard-coded strings matching your particular terminal or vt100 ones which are essentially universal) or you can just static link ncurses. Perhaps you're looking at the Debian-packaged version that's linked to all sorts of silly stuff it doesn't need.. :-)

Comment: @R.. libpam and libtinfo. Anyway, since the problem is not so easy, I'll try to setup a static cross-compiled version of screen.

Comment: Pam is totally unnecessary; it's only used for terminal locking. If you build from source and don't enable pam, it won't be used. I think tinfo is just a light termcap/curses replacement that works fine for screen; you can build it in static if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand your requirements correctly, you could  theoretically use termios struct and ioctl to achieve this.

```
ioctl(0, TIOCNOTTY, NULL);
```

to detach and

```
ioctl(0, TIOCSCTTY, 1);
```

to attach back to the terminal. However, it doesn't actually perform the job.

The following solution describes a not so nice but practical work around

[tty demulsified](http://blog.habets.pp.se/2009/03/Moving-a-process-to-another-terminal)

The primary intention there is to attach program to another terminal but i believe that is the way you can achieve your goal too.

Regarding your mention of embedded platform, you might be able to find some help from [busybox](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html)

It compiles for embedded linux with a pretty small binary and contains most of commonly used linux utilities such as getty, stty etc.

Comment: Actually detaching and attaching a terminal like this will generally not work except for very specialized programs. You probably need an approach like screen where the main part of the program runs on a pseudo-tty and a separate process or thread is responsible for opening and closing a real tty and forwarding data back and forth.

Comment: I guess i meant pretty much the same. I wrote above "It doesn't actually does the job" after describing the api. I think, the link i have referenced (i used a while ago) does something similar to what you have suggested. But your input definitely clarifies it further. Thanks